# Is there any way to manage sessions in iPhone apps?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, google-app-engine, session-cookies

I am working on an iPhone app.

This app has multiple views and every view should send some data to a web server of a user who is logged in.

Is there anything like sessions in iPhone?

How can we tell our iPhone app that a user is logged in and send data to server using his user account?

I am using google app engine(GAE) in on the server side and I am using objective-C for my iphone application.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An iPhone app has all together a different design pattern than a web app. You shouldn't be thinking in terms of sessions unless you are implementing a web based interface. But still you can call `NSUserDefaults` from anywhere of your app and this stores the state information.

I would rather suggest if you have multiple users, create your own custom DB using `Core Data` and handle the managed object context through out your app.

Hope this helps!!